# Is there a logic gate for this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have a set of lights that turn on based on time of day. I want to be able to turn on a separate switch and have the lights blink on and off with a clock I've already built.

So basically, is there a way to ignore input A if input B is detected?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Implies Gate](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Logic_circuit#IMPLIES_Gate). It would allow power flow unless, in your case, B is detected, in which it will be `off`

In the example below we have a 5-clock pulser in the left, this connects to a Implies gate where in `A implies B`. A in this case is your switch saying whether to flash or go off sunlight. On the other side of this switch, we are inverting the switch with a `not gate` and implying with the light detector (In diagram the light detector is the switch close to the clock). These two outputs, the implies clock and implies light and then put into a final `and gate` the output of which powers your lamps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally, instead of a gate, would simply make it to when input B is true it  extends a sticky piston with a block diagonal to a block the circuit from input A to turn it off, or use the T Flip-Flop Memory circuit as a toggle option.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a toggle for your input line, which is easily done with three repeaters, a sticky piston and a block.

[image]

Put the two input lines (clock and daylight sensor) next to each other using repeaters pointing in the same direction. The repeaters cannot transmit via air, but any solid block will do, so moving the solid block will change the input line.